# Difficulty using Moshi's Kotlin codegen

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, moshi

I am trying to use Moshi's Kotlin codegen to get annotation support in Kotlin. Despite following the instructions carefully in the [moshi codegen documentation](https://github.com/square/moshi#codegen), the annotation `JsonClass` in `@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)` is not recognized and I am getting the following error:

`error: incompatible types: NonExistentClass cannot be converted to Annotation@error.NonExistentClass()`

My app `build.gradle` file is as follows:

```
...
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    ...
}

dependencies {
    ...
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.5.0'

    kapt 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.8.0'
}
```

The `@JsonClass` annotation is recognized when I add

`implementation("com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.8.0")`.

However, the [moshi reflection documentation](https://github.com/square/moshi#reflection) indicates that this dependency is only required if using reflection instead of codegen.

Any idea what I'm missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`@JsonClass` is a type in the standard Moshi artifact. Retrofit's `converter-moshi` artifact brings in Moshi transitively but does not have the latest version of Moshi. **Specify `implementation("com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.8.0")`.**

Comment: Encountered this issue recently, also works with 1.12.0